# pybedtools bam_to_bed() bedpe

Tags: python, bedtools

I'm feeling dumb, but I can't figure out the syntax below, and I've been googling the w/o success for a while.

Very easy, I have a bam I want to convert to bedpe with pybedtools within a script.

The following works great:

```
pybed_BAM = pybedtools.BedTool("path/to/sorted/bam")
bedpe = pybed_BAM.bam_to_bed().to_dataframe()
```

however, of course, it results in a normal bed file. If I try to add the bedpe argument as either `pybed_BAM.bam_to_bed("-bedpe")` or `pybed_BAM.bam_to_bed("bedpe")` it fails with:

```
TypeError: handle_kwargs() keywords must be strings
```

Unfortunately the [bam_to_bed() page](https://daler.github.io/pybedtools/autodocs/pybedtools.bedtool.BedTool.bam_to_bed.html#pybedtools.bedtool.BedTool.bam_to_bed) doesn't provide syntax explanation but is simply a copy-paste of the command-line tool help. The above attempts are trying to borrow the syntax from other pybedtools functions but are obviously incorrect. What am I missing?

PS
the file is fine as the conversion from commandline with bedtools bamtobed works fine.

PPS
I'd like to avoid subprocess pipes and use pybedtools

Comment: good idea! unfortunately it gives the same error

Comment: `pybedtools` uses `subprocess` behind the scenes anyway, it seems.

Comment: so, why re-implementing manually something that is done, checked, and maintained in a stable module? ;)
Plus, the code is much cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with an hint from Patrick Artner's suggestion I found the solution

`pybed_BAM.bam_to_bed(bedpe=True)` does the job!